# Angular Material - Spinner - Is it possible to hide elements in IE only?

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, angular-material, microsoft-edge

I have an angular app that use the Angular Material Progress Spinner. Unfortunately, in IE and Edge the loader remains static. Not only that, I display the loader until I have retrieved my data from firestore. For some reason in IE and Edge, the loading overlay remains for about 15 seconds before displaying my data. However, as a test, I removed the loading overlay and my data appears immediately.

1. Is there a way to not display elements in IE / Edge? (This snippet below to be precise)

   ```
   <app-loading-overlay *ngIf="loading"></app-loading-overlay>
   ```
2. Or is there a way to ensure this works in IE / Edge? I'm a little worried about doing an angular material update because I always end up in a gigantic rabbit hole of npm dependencies not syncing and everything falls apart.

**Dependencies**

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^4.4.6",
"@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
"@angular/common": "^4.4.4",
"@angular/compiler": "^4.4.4",
"@angular/core": "^4.4.6",
"@angular/forms": "^4.4.4",
"@angular/http": "^4.4.4",
"@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.4",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.4",
"@angular/router": "^4.4.4",
"@types/algoliasearch": "^3.24.2",
"algoliasearch": "^3.24.5",
"angular-sortablejs": "^2.1.0",
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"firebase": "4.8.0",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
"instantsearch.js": "^2.2.3",
"ngx-color-picker": "^5.3.5",
"rxjs": "^5.4.2",
"sortablejs": "^1.6.1",
"zone.js": "^0.8.14"
},
```

Comment: add css class to all loaders and then make css query targeting only IE and Edge, which is possible as I remember and simply set display:none to class(es) in this query.

Comment: I don't have any problems with spinners or *ngIf in IE11. Are you using the required polyfills for IE11 and Edge? I don't see them in your dependencies.

Comment: I ended up creating a css3 spinner. Turns out the issue wasn't the spinner. It's just my firestore queries taking up to 30 seconds in IE. I have no idea what that is. My colleague posted about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49299742/angularfire-firestore-queries-incredibly-slow-in-internet-explorer-and-microsoft